# c# run method not looping

Tags: c#, cosmos

I am making a simple OS using cosmos.
I am a beginner in c#.
Run() method in cosmos's default code loops until I quit VMware.
However, once I fix little bit, my program exits automatically. I don't understand why. I am trying to make it loop.
Cosmo's default code before I fix:

```
 public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
{
    protected override void BeforeRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cosmos booted successfully. Type a line of text to get it echoed back.");
    }

    protected override void Run()
    {
         Console.Write("Input: ");
         var input = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Write("Text typed: ");
         Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

Below is my new Run() method. Everything else remains the same.

```
protected override void Run() {
    Console.WriteLine("Input:");
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.StartsWith("echo"))
    {
        var index = input.IndexOf("echo");
        var initial = input.Substring(0, index);
        var final = input.Substring(index + "echo".Length);
        var echoInput = initial + final;
            Console.WriteLine(echoInput);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi M.k, what do you mean by trying to make it loop? Do you get to the point where you can type in an input? What do you mean by **my code exits automatically** so if you type in **_echo this is test_** you should see **_this is test_** printed out on the console

Comment: Run() method before I fixed it loops until I quit VMware automatically. But after I fix it, as soon as I input, VMware quits. I do not see my strings printed out on the console.

Comment: you can add `Console.ReadKey()` just after the `if` block statement. that should keep the console open until you hit a key.

Comment: How is the `Run` method called?  Does the ancestor class have some sort of event loop that calls it over and over?  Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

> ***my program exits automatically....***

This is because you have an unchecked exception in the new *run* method at runtime and the application is crashing silently...

The logic here must be debugged and corrected...

```
var index = input.IndexOf("echo");
var initial = input.Substring(0, index);
var final = input.Substring(index + "echo".Length);
var echoInput = initial + final;
Console.WriteLine(echoInput);
```

Check this out:

**input**

"echo world"

Then:

Var index=0

Var initial=""   // empty string

Var final = "echo "// here explodes with an index out of bounds exception  if you give only echo as input

var echoInput = ""+ "echo "

Comment: `var final =` part returns with **`""`** empty string so i'm not sure how you manage to get an index out of bounds exception even with an input of only  **echo**. maybe I'm missing something here.. ^^